# Specify Ionic ion-loading container

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Is there a way to specify the ion-loading container in ionic? The backdrop always blocks the whole app.

I have a few content parts in my SPA. Now when I want to update a specific part of the view, I would like to show ion-loading only in that specific part and not block the whole app.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Add this component where you need

```
<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
```

Comment: I wanted the whole package with: backdrop, spinner with message + in out animation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ion loading which you can customize with loading message as well. refer the official [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/loading). you can see many other options such as skeleton-text, progress bar and spinner as well.